# Content type referenced by another document library's template

Tags: document-library, content-type, document-template

This is my parent content type below. How can I reference this content type from another site collection's document library's template? I've tried using the DocumentTemplate and absolute URL to the template file "LMS.docx" but nothing happens.  I appreciate any help. Thanks.

`<DocumentTemplate TargetName="http://portal.swee.com/sites/learn/Shared%20Documents/Forms/LMS.docx"></DocumentTemplate>`

Parent Content Type:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
<!-- Parent ContentType: LMS Document (LeaveManagementSystem\LMS Document) (0x010100174F5B4B857F41F5893B76351F3001CA) -->
  <ContentType ID="0x010100174F5B4B857F41F5893B76351F3001CA02" 
               Name="LMS Project Document" 
               Group="LMS Content Types" 
               Description="LMS Project Documents Content Type" 
               Inherits="TRUE" 
               Overwrite="TRUE" 
               Version="0">
    <DocumentTemplate TargetName="http://portal.swee.com/sites/learn/Shared%20Documents/Forms/LMS.docx"></DocumentTemplate>
    <FieldRefs>
      <FieldRef ID="{EB703A89-8495-40E8-9F42-180E57EA9F1A}" DisplayName="Name" Required="FALSE" Name="LMS_Name" />
      <FieldRef ID="{8ECEC8EA-560B-40BA-A768-D438AD97DAEF}" DisplayName="Leave Type" Required="FALSE" Name="LMS_LeaveType" />
      <FieldRef ID="{0214FB1B-051A-4861-91DA-C94324FDCD6F}" DisplayName="Start Date" Required="FALSE" Name="LMS_StartDate" Format="DateOnly" />
      <FieldRef ID="{26780D0B-4F9A-4BD5-AD56-74D625F14946}" DisplayName="End Date" Required="FALSE" Name="LMS_EndDate" Format="DateOnly" />
    </FieldRefs>

  </ContentType>
</Elements>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to access content type created in one site collection in another site collection. If this is the case, you would have to use `Content Type Hub` feature of SharePoint.

Please find below links to get idea of what is Content Type Hub and how it can be used:

[Steps to create Content Type Hub](http://innersharepoint.blogspot.in/2013/10/content-types-publishing-across-site.html)

[Content Type Hub Publishing](http://innersharepoint.blogspot.in/2013/10/content-types-publishing-across-site.html)

Comment: That's what I thought but the senior guys are saying it can be done through the content type's xml by inserting the URL.

Comment: Yes, a content type hub is needed.